# Removing install.php in magento after anstalling

Tags: magento, installation

Is it needed to remove install.php from root directory in Magento for security reasons.

Thanks

Comment: You can post this question on the magento stack exchange if you would like

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No it's not. When calling the installer (`install.php`) after you install Magento you will get an error message saying `FAILED ERROR: Magento is already installed`. So there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: But then hackers know that you are running magento and can search for exploits! So delete it! There is no reason for it to exist anymore

Comment: @Black everyone that know what magento is can find out easily that you are running magento just by looking at the page source. So this is not a valid reason to delete it.